# Showing <h1> <h5> text inline using css

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-heading

I want to show "Sentiment analysis" such that S should be much larger then `h5` text.

What's wrong with follwing code:

HTML:

```
<h1>S</h1> <h5>entiment Analysis</h5>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin-left: 36%;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    font-family: "calibri";
    text-decoration:underline;
    white-space: pre;
}

h5 {
    margin-left: 36%;
    color:#C0C0C0;
    font-family: "calibri";
    text-decoration:underline;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[Live code in CodePan](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/HahDr)

Comment: An each H element starts with a new line. Try it by using span or other element.

Comment: You received 6 answers and commented / accepted none. Why?

Comment: Did you solved your issue?

Answer (score 6):

That's a messy code. If you just want to make the first letter Bigger, You can try the following.

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/cfHFt)**

**HTML**

```
<div>Sentiment analysis</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div:first-letter {
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Fine answer but for the font-size px is not recommended!Use em instead of px!

Comment: @AsrafulHaque posted after my answer:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien Do you know where to apply px and em?

Comment: @AsrafulHaque `em` is not compulsory. Its fine if you need relative sizing and responsive support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/890082/surjith-sm  You can follow the website where to use em and where to use px and others https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size Hope the answer

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to align 2 block level elements in the same line, so either you need to make them `inline` or `inline-block` by using `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block`(recommended) or use `<span>` element inside your `h1` like

```
<h1><span>H</span>ello</h1>
```

And than you can target the `H` using

```
h1 > span {
   font-size: 54px;
}
```

If you are looking to target only the first letter, it is better, if you use [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) pseudo, which will save you an element as well.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfvJX/)

> Note: I am using general element selectors here, make sure you use a
>   `class` or an `id` to target the element uniquely.

Comment: The font-size px is not recommended!Use em instead of px!

Comment: @AsrafulHaque not a compulsion,  also nothing to do with the question :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this css rules for proper follow the css rules to render the requirement!


  <style>
  h1:first-line {
            margin-left: 36%;
            color:#C0C0C0;
            font-family: "calibri";
            font-size:1em;
            text-decoration:underline;
            white-space: pre;
            display:inline;
                }
   h1:first-letter{
            margin-left: 36%;
            color:#C0C0C0;
            font-family: "calibri";
            font-size:2em;
            text-decoration:underline;
            white-space: pre;
            display:inline;
                }
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>World</h1>

h1:first-letter {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/ZtL8C/1/)

Comment: The font-size px is not recommended!Use em instead of px!

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
      .style1
    {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
   <span class="style1">S</span>entiment</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline` to both `h1` & `h5`, Then **remove** `margin-left` from `h5`

**[DEMO HERE >>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjtnB)**

Try this

```
 h1
   {
         margin-left: 36%;
         color:#C0C0C0;
         font-family: "calibri";
         text-decoration:underline;
         white-space: pre;
         display:inline;
  }


h5
   {
        color:#C0C0C0;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-decoration:underline;
        white-space: pre;
        display:inline;
   }
```

Your way to implement this seems little complex, even if you want to go with your code you can use my answer, otherwise select any of the simple method in other answers here.